# Как вывести строку без кавычек?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Добрый день. Пытаюсь сделать чат, вывожу текст таким образом

```
<div class="comment">
   @comment.Text
</div>,
```

но когда нужно вывести ссылку, то ссылка экранируется в кавычки и выводится код

```
<a href='Invoices/SaveFile?fileId=210'>NO_NDS.8_9978_9978_5042059767997850001_20150322_6778FDFA-DB06-4EEF-B612-840788CDB994.xml</a>
```

Как данную проблему исправить, чтобы текст выводился не в кавычках?

Comment: Пробовали @Html.Raw? Не вижу связи в примерах, как первое превращается во второе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
<div class="comment">
    @Html.Raw(comment.Text)
</div>
```